# While command in bash "if there's a $string in file.txt... do..."

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, debian

Need help with the while command. I want to run a command if there's a $sitename in playlist.txt

Here's my bash:

```
   cat playlist.txt | grep -e "$sitename" |  sed -e "s/^.*\(http:.*"$sitename".*flv\).*$/\1/g" | sort | uniq > checklist.txt
cat checklist.txt

while [ " While can find $sitename in checklist.txt" ]; do
                qa
         done
```

that's what i have tried already

```
while [ -n "$echopl" ]; do
                    qa
             done

while [ 'grep -q $string checklist.txt >/dev/null' ]; do
                qa
         done

while [  "grep -q "$string" checklist.txt" ]; do
                qa2
         done
while grep -q "$string" checklist.txt; do
    qa
done

while grep -q '$string' checklist.txt; do
    qa
done


if grep -q "$string" checklist.txt ; then
  qa
fi
```

Temporarily I put many if commands :(

ifmorelinks
ifmorelinks
ifmorelinks
ifmorelinks
ifmorelinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if grep "$string" checklist.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  qa
fi
```

Comment: From man grep(1): _Portability note: unlike GNU grep, 7th Edition Unix grep did not conform to POSIX, because it lacked -q and its -s option behaved like GNU grep's -q option. USG-style grep also lacked -q but its -s option behaved like GNU grep. Portable shell scripts should avoid both -q and -s and should redirect standard and error output to /dev/null instead._

Comment: There's a problem with this solution: if `$string` contains a regex metacharacter, it will be interpreted! So, if you have, say 'a.com' in your string, it will match 'fatcomparse.org' in your checklist. You'd better use `fgrep` instead, or `grep -F`. Also, consider the `-w` option.

Answer (score 2):

```
while grep -q "$string" checklist.txt; do
    qa
done
```

If `$string` means literally `$string` and not the value of `string` variable, use this:

```
while grep -q '$string' checklist.txt; do
    qa
done
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried that already. qa runs even if there's no "$string" in checklist.txt

Comment: well, then your file still contains the string. How exactly do you modify the file?