# While loop, username in /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

How would I go about writing a while loop that says: While a username is in the /etc/passwd file, do (command)? 
I'm trying to use a command such as `grep -q "^{usern}:" /etc/passwd` but I'm not sure how to put that as the condition of the while loop.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551382/while-command-in-bash-if-theres-a-string-in-file-txt-do

Answer (score 3):

To loop over the users in `/etc/passwd` and do something with each user, try the following:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | while IFS= read -r user
do
    echo "$user"
    # do something with $user
done
```

If you want to check whether a specific user exists in `/etc/passwd` and then do something, use an if-statement:

```
if grep -q "^username:" /etc/passwd
then
    # do something
fi
```